# Addevent listener debugger not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I have a html file and am trying to call as Js function externally inside it.

can someone help me with the 3 numbered problems below

```
document.getElementById('aa-button').addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu(){
  var targetDiv = document.getElementById("aa-navigation__items");
  debugger; //1) THIS IS NOT WORKING
  console.log(targetDiv); //THIS RETURNS THE CORRECT THING
  targetDiv.classList.toggle("reveal"); //2) THIS DOES NOT WORK
  targetDiv.className += " reveal"; //THIS DOES WORK
}
```

3) How can i call the function without the event listener?

Comment: So 1st step will be to inspect your "aa-button" in the developer tools (Press F12 > Go to elements), now you'll want to find the section which tells you about what events are attached to that element. If under the "click" section you do not see this function you'll know your eventListner isn't being attached correctly (Which we can look to fix next)

Comment: @does_not_compute I can confirm that after following your instructions it IS being attached correctly

Comment: Ok fair enough, so what you can do it just open your devtools again and head to the "console" section, If you simply type "toggleMenu()" your function will get called, if you type "toggleMenu" you should see your function print out into the console (As it's actually just a variable in javascript). Add your debugger statement above the "targetDiv" line as maybe this is erroring (Again this should get caught in your console log if this is the case)

Comment: @does_not_compute I don't get why debugger doesn't get called even when the first line in my function though. at least if that worked I could get in and play around a bit

Comment: What happens when you type "toggleMenu" in console, do you see it print out the contents of your function? What happens when you call "toggleMenu()" straight from the console?

Comment: @does_not_compute cheers for the help buddy. my friend found the issue coz i was firing the function twice (forgot to remove it from onclick) and therefore the toggle was happening twice very quickly to give the appearance it wasn't happening when it was! cheers tho